# is there a way of getting abundance data out of a list of tuples in python

Tags: python, count, tuples, regression, counting

I have a dataset that looks something like this:

```
Species = [(30, "cat"), (30, "dog"), (30, "bird"), (45, "cat"), (45, "dog"), (60, "bird"), (70, "lizard"), (70, "frog")]
```

and what I'm trying to do is count the number of species at each location so I can run a regression.
So I think I need my output to be something like this

```
location = (30,45,60,70)
species_num = (3,2,1,2)
```

Does anyone know where I should start? I've been working on it for hours and every time I think I'm getting close it doesn't work.

Comment: Please try to include some of the code you've tried in your question.

Comment: Also, please consider accepting an answer so others know the issue is resolved. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution using numpy or pandas

[`numpy.unique(return_counts=True)`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) addresses exactly what you are looking for. The number component is extracted by `list(zip(*Species))[0]`.

```
import numpy as np
location, species_num = np.unique(list(zip(*Species))[0], return_counts=True)
```

Or alternatively, `pandas.DataFrame.groupby().size()`:

```
import pandas as pd
sr = pd.DataFrame(Species, columns=["location", "animal"])\
       .groupby("location").size()
location = sr.index.values
species_num = sr.values
```

### Output

```
print(location)
Out[136]: array([30, 45, 60, 70])

print(species_num)
Out[137]: array([3, 2, 1, 2])
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) from Collections module, it will return a dict where the keys are the numbers and the value is the occurence.

```
from collections import Counter
counter = Counter(sp[0] for sp in Species) 
>>> counter
   Counter({30: 3, 45: 2, 60: 1, 70: 2})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use python Counter to count values.Try this

```
from collections import Counter
count = [i[0] for i in Species]
counter = Counter(count)
values = counter.values()
keys = counter.keys()
```

output

```
counter.values()
dict_values([3, 2, 1, 2])

counter.keys()
dict_keys([30, 45, 60, 70])
```

Answer (score 0):

Counter from collections module creates dictionary for unique element and count of it in an iterable.

```
   from collections import Counter
   my_list = [field[0] for field in Species]

   count = Counter(my_list)
   count
```

Comment: Please explain your solution; never just post code on its own.